# In AngularJs cannot load ng-view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

iam new in angularJs.i am using wamp server and it loads to the html page but doesnot shows the view.i have used ng-app in body also but it doesnot loads the view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJs | Basic Login Form</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--  -->
</head>
<body>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'page.html'
    })
    .when('/hello',{
        templateUrl:'hello.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'

    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works when using the latest libraries of Angular (I couldn't find router 1.2.23, which is pretty outdated anyway), as you can see here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/OOSHyNjIIIibeX03pVuB?p=preview

This is the code i've changed:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<!--  -->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

By the way, you have duplicate body tag. You might want to remove that.